# How to consume routerlicious without experimental packages?

Tags: fluid-framework

My application works fine with the tinylicious server, but I would like to consume routerlicious server without using deprecated experimental packages.

The server run in local docker container alfred run on port 3003)

My code to connect the client

```js
  client = new AzureClient({
        connection: {
            tenantId: "local",
            tokenProvider: new InsecureTokenProvider("local", { id: "local" }),
            orderer: "http://localhost:3003",
            storage: "http://localhost:3003",
        }
    });

    containerSchema: ContainerSchema = {
        initialObjects: { diagram: SharedMap },
        dynamicObjectTypes: [SharedMap]
    };
```

The following code make an error (see stacktrace)

```js
    const { container } = await this.client.createContainer(this.containerSchema);

    const json = JSON.parse(diagram.model.toJson());

    const map = container.initialObjects.diagram as SharedMap;

    map.set("json", json)

    const id = await container.attach();
```

Stacktrace

```
xhr.js:187 POST http://localhost:3003/documents/local 403 (Forbidden)
    dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:187
    xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
    dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:53
    request @ Axios.js:108
    wrap @ bind.js:9
    (anonymous) @ restWrapper.ts:45
    schedule @ rateLimiter.ts:41
    async function (async)
    schedule @ rateLimiter.ts:40
    request @ restWrapper.ts:45
    post @ restWrapper.ts:51
    createContainer @ documentServiceFactory.ts:85
    async function (async)
    createContainer @ documentServiceFactory.ts:77
    (anonymous) @ container.ts:872
    runWithRetry @ runWithRetry.ts:28
    attach @ container.ts:872
    async function (async)
    attach @ container.ts:869
    attach @ AzureClient.ts:83
    attach @ fluidContainer.ts:59
    createDiagram @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:96
    async function (async)
    createDiagram @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:89
    initDiagram @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:76
    ReactDiagram.componentDidMount @ gojsreact.js:31
    commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20663
    commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
    callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
    invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
    commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
    unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
    runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
    commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
    performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
    (anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11327
    unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
    runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
    flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11322
    flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11309
    flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:22467
    scheduleRefresh @ react-dom.development.js:24429
    (anonymous) @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:304
    performReactRefresh @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:293
    (anonymous) @ RefreshUtils.js:62
    setTimeout (async)
    enqueueUpdate @ RefreshUtils.js:60
    (anonymous) @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:190
    ./src/pages/FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:190
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
    hotApplyInternal @ bootstrap:749
    hotApply @ bootstrap:411
    (anonymous) @ bootstrap:386
    Promise.then (async)
    hotUpdateDownloaded @ bootstrap:385
    hotAddUpdateChunk @ bootstrap:361
    webpackHotUpdateCallback @ bootstrap:57
    (anonymous) @ main.4bde7b0b05d944bfa188.hot-update.js:1
    index.js:1 fluid:telemetry:Container containerAttach {"retry":0,"duration":43,"category":"error","error":"Request failed with status code 403","errorType":"authorizationError","errorInstanceId":"ce2a437d-8e10-4107-b7fc-46b3fccb5e75","statusCode":403,"fluidErrorCode":"Request failed with status code 403","canRetry":false,"message":"Request failed with status code 403","clientType":"interactive","loaderVersion":"0.47.1","containerId":"5e715267-6c7a-4cd0-be23-944edbcc8c7d","docId":"","containerAttachState":"Attaching","containerLoaded":true,"dmInitialSeqNumber":0,"dmLastKnownSeqNumber":0,"loaderId":"92424f7f-11de-4644-97a7-e19696c11251"} tick=44612 Error    at createR11sNetworkError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:26300:14)    at throwR11sNetworkError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:26326:24)    at RouterliciousOrdererRestWrapper.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:26543:80)    at async RouterliciousDocumentServiceFactory.createContainer (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:25875:24)    at async runWithRetry (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:21523:16)    at async Container.attach (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:4915:24)    at async FluidContainer.attach [as attachCallback] (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:2237:7)    at async FluidframeworkDiagram.createDiagram (http://localhost:3000/main.4bde7b0b05d944bfa188.hot-update.js:112:16) +0ms
    console.<computed> @ index.js:1
    debug @ common.js:113
    send @ debugLogger.ts:124
    send @ logger.ts:327
    sendTelemetryEventCore @ logger.ts:150
    sendErrorEvent @ logger.ts:160
    runWithRetry @ runWithRetry.ts:39
    async function (async)
    runWithRetry @ runWithRetry.ts:28
    attach @ container.ts:872
    async function (async)
    attach @ container.ts:869
    attach @ AzureClient.ts:83
    attach @ fluidContainer.ts:59
    createDiagram @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:96
    async function (async)
    createDiagram @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:89
    initDiagram @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:76
    ReactDiagram.componentDidMount @ gojsreact.js:31
    commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20663
    commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
    callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
    invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
    invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
    commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:23151
    unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
    runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
    commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22990
    performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:22329
    (anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:11327
    unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
    runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
    flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @ react-dom.development.js:11322
    flushSyncCallbackQueue @ react-dom.development.js:11309
    flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:22467
    scheduleRefresh @ react-dom.development.js:24429
    (anonymous) @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:304
    performReactRefresh @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:293
    (anonymous) @ RefreshUtils.js:62
    setTimeout (async)
    enqueueUpdate @ RefreshUtils.js:60
    (anonymous) @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:190
    ./src/pages/FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx @ FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:190
    __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:856
    hotApplyInternal @ bootstrap:749
    hotApply @ bootstrap:411
    (anonymous) @ bootstrap:386
    Promise.then (async)
    hotUpdateDownloaded @ bootstrap:385
    hotAddUpdateChunk @ bootstrap:361
    webpackHotUpdateCallback @ bootstrap:57
    (anonymous) @ main.4bde7b0b05d944bfa188.hot-update.js:1
    FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:98 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 403
        at createR11sNetworkError (errorUtils.ts:62)
        at throwR11sNetworkError (errorUtils.ts:82)
        at RouterliciousOrdererRestWrapper.request (restWrapper.ts:81)
        at async RouterliciousDocumentServiceFactory.createContainer (documentServiceFactory.ts:85)
        at async runWithRetry (runWithRetry.ts:28)
        at async Container.attach (container.ts:872)
        at async FluidContainer.attach [as attachCallback] (AzureClient.ts:83)
        at async FluidframeworkDiagram.createDiagram (FluidframeworkDiagram.tsx:96)
```

package.json

```json
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@fluidframework/azure-client": "^0.47.1",
        "@fluidframework/server-services-client": "^0.1030.0",
        "@fluidframework/tinylicious-client": "^0.47.0",
        "@teamwork/websocket-json-stream": "^2.0.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
        "@types/node": "^12.20.24",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
        "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8",
        "fluid-framework": "^0.47.0",
        "gojs": "^2.1.48",
        "gojs-react": "^1.1.0",
        "luxon": "^2.0.2",
        "react": "^17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
        "react-router": "^5.2.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
        "typescript": "^4.4.2",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2",
        "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "start-server-fluid": "npx tinylicious",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a 403 because your requests aren't authenticated (i.e. signed with a token that the Routerlicious service accepts). Tinylicious doesn't have auth, but Routerlicious does. The R11s auth model is very similar to the one used in Azure Fluid Relay, so the docs here are useful background:

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-fluid-relay/concepts/authentication-authorization

TL;DR summary of the auth model is that it's tenant-based; each tenant has a secret key that must be used to sign bearer tokens for the R11s service to accept the requests.

The R11s tenants are configured in the server/routerlicious/packages/routerlicious/config/config.json file here:

https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/blob/release/0.50/server/routerlicious/packages/routerlicious/config/config.json#L77-L90

If you're using the R11s docker images, then you can use the default `fluid` tenant ID with the tenant secret that's in the config file, along with InsecureTokenProvider. For example:

```
// IMPORTANT: RouterliciousClient does not exist!
const client = new RouterliciousClient({
    connection: {
        tenantId: "fluid", // This is a default tenant that exists in the default R11s config.
        tokenProvider: new InsecureTokenProvider("create-new-tenants-if-going-to-production", {
            id: "userId",
            name: "Test User",
        }),
        orderer: "http://localhost:3005",
        storage: "http://localhost:3001",
    }
});
```

If you want to add more tenants you can put them in that file and restart the service/rebuild the docker image.

Finally, note that there is no RouterliciousClient. You *can* use AzureClient with R11s, but that's only an accident of history, and won't remain true.

Comment: Looks like AzureClient doesn't work with R11s at the moment, but this will be addressed by this PR for Routerlicious: <https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/pull/8060>